# jQuery function if statement

Tags: jquery, function

I've created a function called VoteSlide. When I click on on the buttons `.prev` and `.next` it does execute the function. But as you can see the function reacts the same to both buttons. So I want the function to react different when a different button is pushed. One function should have `margin-left -100%` and the other should have `margin-left: 100%`

But how do I create that small difference? I was thinking about using an if/else statement. But I haven't used to enough to figure out how to apply it in this case (or if it's the right way to solve this).

```
function VoteSlide() {

  var prev = this;
  $(prev).find(".output").html(function(i, val){return val*1+1});
  $(prev).removeClass("prev")

  $("body").find(".art").each(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<img src="http://no-illusions.nl/random/demo1/assets/images/' + images[index] + '">');
    if(index < images.length+0 ){
      index++;
    }
    else{
      $("#nav" ).fadeOut();
    };
  });

  $(this).closest('body').find(".art img:last").stop().animate
  ({'margin-left': '-100%',}, 500,
   function(){
     $(this).remove();
     $(prev).addClass("prev");
   }
  );
}

$('#nav').delegate('.prev', 'click', VoteSlide);
$('#nav').delegate('.next', 'click', VoteSlide);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if statement to check the class of the button that was clicked, to determine if it was the `prev` or `next` button. Try putting it at the very top of the `VoteSlide` function:

```
if($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
  var margin = '-100%';
} else {
  var margin = '100%';
}
```

Then use the margin variable here:

```
$(this).closest('body').find(".art img:last").stop().animate(
   {'margin-left': margin},
   500,
   function(){
     $(this).remove();
     $(prev).addClass("prev");
   }
);
```

Comment: You made a small typo in your first post, but it gave me the right answer! A question though, what happens if you have more then 5 buttons to choose from? Do you have to write a lot of if/else statements? Or is there an better way?

Comment: Not sure I completely follow. Should each button click change the outcome of the `VoteSlide` method differently? You should be able to iterate on the code a bit and make it work more efficiently as you code.